# calling function on jquery selector

Tags: jquery

Okay, normally I would consider myself an intermediate user of jquery, but this seems like a very noob issue that I'm not quite sure how to code.

I have one div that I want to run a function against.  The only way I'm aware of how to do this is something like...

```
$("#divname").each(function(){
  dostuff();
});
```

This seems like a bit more work when I know there will only be one element.  I tried this...

```
$("#divname", function(){ 
  console.log($(this));
});
```

... but it writes out the whole dom.  I just want to run the function on this one element.  How do I do that?

Comment: @JonathanSampson. LoL, My answer would have been exactly the same if there wasn't 30 chars answer limit... :)

Comment: @gdoron It's actually not the best approach. It prevents you from using `doStuff` as a callback later on in other jQuery iterations since you refer to a parameter rather than `this`. See my answer for details.

Comment: @JonathanSampson. It depends on what the OP wants do. He didn't mention what exactly does he want to do.

Comment: @gdoron He showed `doStuff` in a call to `each`, so I assume it's a function he wants to be able to run on many items, but also run explicitly on one item.

Comment: @JonathanSampson. I upvoted already as it was better than mine. But I do suggest the OP to give more context in his questions, knowing we are not sitting next to him or having crystal ball could help even more. `:)` And by the way, it looks like he accept my style answer and not yours... :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you maintain that each element in HTML DOM has unique `id` that means no two elements have same `id`, then `$('#divname')` always return a single element and `$('#divname').each()` will run one time. not more than one.

Now in your case you want something like

```
dosomething( $('#divname') );
```

For example:

```
function doSomething( el ) {
   el.append('<span>hello</span>');
}

 doSomething( $('#divname') );
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/QStkd/170/)**

Answer (score 28):

You should [call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h2ak8h2y%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) the function, passing your element in as its object:

```
function doStuff() {
    alert( $(this).html() );
}

doStuff.call( $("#foo")[0] );
```

Due to the way we built and call `doStuff`, we can still use it as a callback on `.each`:

```
$(".bar").each( doStuff );
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/WuyJc/